# Quicklists don't work for specific applications

Tags: quicklists

I use Unity launcher Quicklists for libreoffice and some other applications, mostly to open certain commonly consulted files. This works fine. However, for evince and gnome-terminal, none of my quicklists show up: I just get the option to unlock the application from the launcher or launch it.

For reference, here's what I have to try to test evince.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Evince Document Viewer
Comment=Evince
GenericName=Document Viewer
Exec=evince
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=evince
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Office;Viewer;Graphics;2DGraphics;VectorGraphics;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-xzpdf;application/x-ext-pdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostscript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;application/x-ext-ps;application/x-ext-eps;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi;application/x-gzdvi;application/x-ext-dvi;image/vnd.djvu;application/x-ext-djv;application/x-ext-djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cb7;application/x-cbt;application/x-ext-cbr;application/x-ext-cbz;application/x-ext-cb7;application/x-ext-cbt;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=blablah;

[Desktop Action blahblah]
Name[en_CA]=BLahatat
Name=blahblah
Exec=evince
```

Comment: Confirm your version, and whether you effectively use the Unity desktop (`printenv DESKTOP_SESSION`)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 21.10, and "$ printenv DESKTOP_SESSION" returns "unity".